# Gboard Keyboard: Numeric inputType not working on EditText in ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-keypad, gboard

I am using default Android [**Gboard keyboard**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin). But there is an issue when I am using `inputType="number"` on the `EditText`. The keyboard shown but type values not display in `EditText`, also not getting any type value in TextWatcher.

The `EditText` in the `ListView` element looks like the following:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextChecked"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"      
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
```

The `ListView` is defined as:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewDialog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottom"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editTextSearch"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
```

This is my TextWather Code :-

```
 holder.etCheck.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            Log.e("text",""+s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you show your `TextWatcher` code.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ?

Comment: @CodeGeek nopes, however the work around is you can allow permissible characters in android:digit="01234" only these will be typed from keyboard in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

The thing with `TextWatcher` is that it doesn't work so well with `ListView`s. You have to define your own custom `TextWatcher` like this:

```
private class MyCustomEditTextListener implements TextWatcher {
    private int position;

    public void updatePosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
        // do your operations here.
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        Logger.e(TAG, "After" + editable.toString());
    }      
}
```

and inside `getView()` do this:

```
((Viewholder) holder).myCustomEditTextListener.updatePosition(position);
```

Finally inside your `viewHolder` initialise your `EditText` and add the custom `TextWatcher` to it.